# Using DialogFragment

Tags: android

I want to throw a `Dialog` to the user of my app to confirm some action. From the developers API guides I learnt that they prefer using `DialogFragments` instead of dialog class.The activity which should show the dialog is a `ListActivity` and already has been coded.

My question is, if I need to use the `DialogFragment` then my activity may still extend `ListActivity`? Or I need to extend `FragmentActivity` (my app has min sdk 2.3.6) as I know android does not support multiple inheritence?

**I dont want to use** `ListFragments`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check this tutorial about DialogFragments in Android : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/897/using-dialogfragments-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the `android-support-v4` library and then create a class that extends `FragmentActivity` but import this line `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;` to support fragments from v2.3.6 and up. Change your `ListActivity` class to then extend `ListFragment` and invoke the class from your `FragmentActivity`. You can then use the `DialogFragment` with other fragments. This will change the whole structure of your project but it will force you to use better up to date api code.

Seeing that you don't want to use `ListFragment` I wouldn't go through all this trouble of converting all your classes into `Fragments` just to use `DialogFragment` you can just use normal `Dialogs`, they aren't a deprecated api so I wouldn't say there's anything wrong with them.

I think the reason `DialogFragments` are preferred is because they want you to use `Fragments` when developing your app, due to versatility for Tablet apps ect.

Hope this helps